# How to filter attribute collection in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute

I have added the Straps attribute for product...

[image]

I want to filter out the attribute collection...

```
    public function offer()
    {
      $productcollection = $this->_productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*') ->addAttributeToFilter('staps', 'regular');            
      echo count($productcollection);exit;
    }
```

But I can't get the answer.....

How to do that...

Thanks

Comment: try `$this->_productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('fabric') ->addAttributeToFilter('fabric', 'silk');`

Comment: still not getting custom attribute collection

Comment: have you checked in inspect element is silk option value is silk?

Comment: Please answer your question with the solution and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

As per as, my screenshot, **fabric is a multi-select attribute**, So i *can not filter a product collection by multi-Select attribute's option label*, i should **use that option's id**.

```
    protected $_attributeRepository;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }
    
    public function getOptionIdbyAttributeCodeandLabel($attr_code,$optionText)
    {
       $attribute =$this->attributeRepository->get($attr_code);
       $optionId = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($optionText); 
       return $optionId;
    }
    
    public function offer()
    {
       $optionId = $this->getOptionIdbyAttributeCodeandLabel('fabric', 'silk')
       $productcollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('fabric')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('fabric',  $optionId);            

       echo count($productcollection);
       return count($productcollection);
     }
```

Comment: How to check particular product has Straps attribute value "Regular"?@Amit

Comment: @Amit, many syntax error in code, function name is not correct, semicolon missing in many places

Comment: Hello, How can I use multiple select options multiple filter in one phtml. e.g. First I want to show silk products, below them "regular" products and etc. How can I do that in list.phtml with collection filter ? Its only working for one time in foreach loop.